# Count multivalue image field values in views-view-fields.html.twig

Tags: 8, views, theming

Making a presentation template for the gallery. The photo gallery has an image field with multiple values. I need to output the number of gallery photos (in the field_gallery_photo). How do I do this? I tried adding a field with a photo to the view, and all the values are shown in one line. The result is not accurate:

```
{{ fields.field_gallery_photo.content | length }}
```

---

In version 7 I did the following:

1. added the nid field
2. redefined the template for it
3. specified the following in the template:

   ```
   $node = node_load($output);
   print sizeof($node->field_gallery_photo['und']);
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your D7 PHP would translate into D8 Twig like this:

```
{% set node = row._entity %}
{{ node.field_gallery_photo.getvalue | length }}
```